# Minimum Lexicographical String after K removals of first, second, last or penultimate characters

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

**Question:**

Given a string S `S.length() <= 5.10^5` and an integer K `K <= S.length()`. For each removal, you can:

- Remove the **first** character of the string
- Remove the **second** character of the string
- Remove the **last** character of the string
- Remove the **second last** character of the string

How can I do exactly K removals such that the final string has minimum lexicographical order?

**Example:**

S= "abacaaba", K = 2

- Remove the **second** character of the string
- Remove the **second last** character of the string

The final string: "aacaaa" which is the smallest lexicographical possible.

**P/S:**

I've tried for many days but can't figure out an efficience way to solve this problem. But I think there's something to do with dynamic programming.

Comment: Could I ask what is the source of the problem?

Comment: @LearningMathematics its from a contest of my school

Comment: @unglinh279 Should we use all K removals?

Comment: @Nikxp yes, we have to use all K removals

Comment: the final output of the algorithm is the sequence of moves or just the smallest lexicographical string?

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi just the smallest lexicographical string

Comment: @unglinh279 I don't think I understand the example you give, the minimum lexicographical order is given by the string "aaaaba" which can be achieved by removing the second to first element twice. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ldog After removing the first "b", you have "aacaaba", "c" is located at the thrid character, thus cannot be removed.

Comment: Please clarify which lexicographical order you mean, there are two common definitions: (1) If two words have different lengths, the usual lexicographical order pads the shorter one with "blanks" (a special symbol that is treated as smaller than every element of A) at the end until the words are the same length, and then the words are compared as in the previous case.

Comment: (2) However, in combinatorics, another convention is frequently used for the second case, whereby a shorter sequence is always smaller than a longer sequence. This variant of the lexicographical order is sometimes called shortlex order. Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order

Comment: @ldog What difference does it make? Could you give an example?

Comment: Just read we are forced to use K deletions and a no-op is not allowed, in this case we will never have a resulting sequence of different length. If no-ops were allowed this could make a difference.

Comment: @ldog A shorter identical string (for existing characters) will always be compared less than the other if you append it with "blanks" that are smaller than the alphabets

Comment: @unglinh279: there exists a linear algorithm which does not use suffix arrays to solve this problem, let me know if you are interested I could code it up. It requires tracking differences while shifting the middle portions, and is concenptually simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a (hopefully) mostly complete solution in Python (sorry, I'm even less versed in C++). The idea is I believe the same or very similar to David Eisenstat's, who's answer helped me think more about handling the middles. The comparisons for the middle section use O(1) lookups with O(n log n) preprocessing based on the suffix array construction referenced and linked in the code (David's suggestion is to use O(n) preprocessing and O(1) lookups but I haven't had time to get into O(1) RMQs or Ukkonen's; I'm also charmed by the referenced CP suffix array algorithm). The code includes testing comparing with brute-force but is incomplete in that it does not handle the case where there are only the prefix and suffix and no middle, which should be much simpler to handle anyway. There are probably ways to make the code more succinct and organised but I haven't had time yet to consider it more carefully.

Since we can remove the first, second, penultimate or last characters; the first two letters of the solution will be chosen from two letters (a subsequence) remaining after k or less deletions:

```
xxxAxxxxxxxB...
```

Once we've committed to character A by deleting some first characters, we are left only with a choice for B, based on how many deletions we make of the second character. Clearly, we'd like the lowest available character for A, which we may have more than one instance of, and the lowest choice for B after that, for which we also may have more than once instance of.

The suffix is composed similarly, but we need to store the best suffix for each k - num_deletions already chosen for the prefix. Then the final candidate is the lowest two-character-prefix + middle + two-character-suffix, where the middle is fixed by the distribution of deletions in each candidate. We can compare middles using a suffix array or tree with additional information.

Python

```py
def log2(n):
  i = -1
  while(n):
    i += 1
    n >>= 1
  return i

# https://cp-algorithms.com/string/suffix-array.html
def sort_cyclic_shifts(s):
  n = len(s)
  alphabet = 256
  cs = []

  p = [0] * n
  c = [0] * n
  cnt = [0] * max(alphabet, n + 1)

  for i in range(n):
    cnt[ord(s[i])] += 1
  for i in range(1, alphabet):
    cnt[i] += cnt[i-1]
  for i in range(n):
    cnt[ord(s[i])] -= 1
    p[cnt[ord(s[i])]] = i
  c[p[0]] = 0
  classes = 1
  for i in range(1, n):
    if s[p[i]] != s[p[i-1]]:
      classes += 1
    c[p[i]] = classes - 1

  cs.append(c[:])

  pn = [0] * n
  cn = [0] * n
  h = 0

  while (1 << h) < n:
    for i in range(n):
      pn[i] = p[i] - (1 << h)
      if pn[i] < 0:
        pn[i] += n
      
    for i in range(0, classes):
      cnt[i] = 0

    for i in range(n):
      cnt[c[pn[i]]] += 1
    for i in range(1, classes):
      cnt[i] += cnt[i-1]
    for i in range(n-1, -1, -1):
      cnt[c[pn[i]]] -= 1
      p[cnt[c[pn[i]]]] = pn[i]
    cn[p[0]] = 0
    classes = 1
    for i in range(i, n):
      cur = c[p[i]], c[(p[i] + (1 << h)) % n]
      prev = c[p[i-1]], c[(p[i-1] + (1 << h)) % n]
      if cur != prev:
        classes += 1
      cn[p[i]] = classes - 1
    c = cn
    cs.append(c[:])
    h += 1

  return p, cs

# https://cp-algorithms.com/string/suffix-array.html
def suffix_array_construction(s):
  s += "$"
  sorted_shifts, cs = sort_cyclic_shifts(s)
  return sorted_shifts[1:], cs

# https://cp-algorithms.com/string/suffix-array.html
def compare(i, j, l, k, n, c):
  a = c[k][i], c[k][(i+l-(1 << k))%n]
  b = c[k][j], c[k][(j+l-(1 << k))%n]
  if a == b:
    return 0
  elif a < b:
    return -1
  return 1


## MAIN FUNCTION


def f(s, k):
  debug = 0

  n = len(s)

  # Best prefix
  best_first = s[k]
  best_second = s[k+1]
  first_idxs = [k]
  second_idxs = [k + 1]

  for i in range(k - 1, -1, -1):
    if s[i] <= best_first:
      best_first = s[i]
      # We only need one leftmost index
      first_idxs = [i]
  for i in range(k, first_idxs[0], -1):
    if (s[i] < best_second):
      best_second = s[i]
      second_idxs = [i]
    elif s[i] == best_second:
      second_idxs.append(i)

  second_idxs = list(reversed(second_idxs))

  # Best suffix
  # For each of l deletions,
  # we can place the last
  # character anywhere ahead
  # of the penultimate.
  last_idxs = {(n - 2): [n - 1]}
  best_last = s[n - 1]
  for l in range(2, k + 2):
    idx = n - l
    if s[idx] < best_last:
      best_last = s[idx]
      last_idxs[n - 1 - l] = [idx]
    else:
      last_idxs[n - 1 - l] = last_idxs[n - l]

  p, cs = suffix_array_construction(s)

  second_idx = 0

  if debug:
    print(first_idxs, second_idxs, last_idxs)

  while first_idxs[0] >= second_idxs[second_idx]:
    second_idx += 1

  prefix_end = second_idxs[second_idx]
  num_deleted = prefix_end - 1
  remaining = k - num_deleted
  suffix_start = n - remaining - 2
  best = (prefix_end + 1, suffix_start - 1)

  while second_idx < len(second_idxs):
    prefix_end = second_idxs[second_idx]
    num_deleted = prefix_end - 1
    remaining = k - num_deleted
    suffix_start = n - remaining - 2

    len_candidate_middle = suffix_start - 1 - prefix_end

    # The prefixes are all equal.
    # We need to compare the middle
    # and suffix.
    # compare(i, j, l, k, n, c)
    len_best_middle = best[1] - best[0] + 1
    l = min(len_candidate_middle, len_best_middle)

    # Compare middles
    comp = compare(best[0], prefix_end + 1, l, log2(l), n + 1, cs)

    # Candidate is better
    if comp == 1:
      best = (prefix_end + 1, suffix_start - 1)
    elif comp == 0:
      # Compare suffix of candidate with
      # substring at the comparable position
      # of best.
      [last_idx] = last_idxs[suffix_start]
      candidate_suffix = s[suffix_start] + s[last_idx]

      if len_candidate_middle < len_best_middle:
        # One character of best's suffix
        if len_candidate_middle + 1 == len_best_middle:
          to_compare = s[best[1]] + s[best[1] + 1]
        # None of best's suffix
        else:
          idx = best[0] + len_candidate_middle
          to_compare = s[idx] + s[idx + 1]
        # If the candidate suffix is equal
        # to best's equivalent, the candidate
        # wins since it's shorter.
        if candidate_suffix <= to_compare:
          best = (prefix_end + 1, suffix_start - 1)

      elif len_candidate_middle == len_best_middle:
        idx = best[1] + 1
        to_compare = s[idx] + s[last_idxs[idx][0]]
        if candidate_suffix < to_compare:
          best = (prefix_end + 1, suffix_start - 1)

      # len_best_middle < len_candidate_middle 
      else:
        # One character of candidate's suffix
        if len_best_middle + 1 == len_candidate_middle:
          to_compare = s[suffix_start - 1] + s[suffix_start]
        # None of candidates's suffix
        else:
          idx = prefix_end + 1 + len_best_middle
          to_compare = s[idx] + s[idx + 1]

        if candidate_suffix < to_compare:
          best = (prefix_end + 1, suffix_start - 1)

    second_idx += 1

  prefix = s[first_idxs[0]] + s[second_idxs[second_idx-1]]
  middle = s[best[0]:best[1] + 1]
  suffix = s[best[1] + 1] + s[last_idxs[best[1] + 1][0]]

  return prefix + middle + suffix


def brute_force(s, k):
  best = s + "z"
  stack = [(s, k)]

  while stack:
    _s, _k = stack.pop()
    if _k == 0:
      best = min(best, _s)
      continue
    stack.append((_s[1:], _k - 1))
    stack.append((_s[0] + _s[2:], _k - 1))
    stack.append((_s[0:len(_s)-1], _k - 1))
    stack.append((_s[0:len(_s)-2] + _s[-1], _k - 1))

  return best

#    01234567
#s = "abacaaba"
#k = 2

# Test
import random

n = 12
num_tests = 500

for _ in range(num_tests):
  s = "".join([chr(97 + random.randint(0, 25)) for i in range(n)])
  k = random.randint(1, n - 5)
  #print(s, k)
  _f = f(s, k)
  brute = brute_force(s, k)
  if brute != _f:
    print("MISMATCH!")
    print(s, k)
    print(_f)
    print(brute)
    break

print("Done.")
```

Comment: FYI this algorithm fails for me for `n>=300`

Comment: @ldog thanks for discovering that and letting me know! It appears to either be an error in how I translated the CP algorithm or possibly it their implementation itself. I'll look at that later.

Answer (score 4):

All together, these ideas should lead to a linear-time algorithm.

If K ≤ N−4, the final string has at least four characters. Its two-character prefix is the least two-character subsequence of the (K+2)-character prefix of the initial string. Compute this prefix and the possible positions of its second character. This can be accomplished in O(K) time by scanning through first K+2 characters, maintaining the least character so far and the least two-character subsequence so far.

Now that we know the two-character prefix, we just have to determine the best suffix. For a prefix that required J deletions to set up, the final string continues with the next N−4 − K characters that we can't touch, followed by the least two-character subsequence of the (K+2 − J)-character suffix of the initial string. We can compute the least two-character subsequence of each of the relevant suffixes using the scanning algorithm described previously. The one tricky part is comparing the untouchable middles efficiently. This can be accomplished with some difficulty using a suffix array with longest common prefixes.

If K > N−4, just return the least (N−K)-character subsequence.

Comment: Isn't there a log factor to either compare or preprocess to compare the substrings using the suffix array?

Comment: @גלעדברקן for large alphabets, yes.

Comment: My understanding from the little I read is that to compare substrings of equal, arbitrary length we'd need all `log(|s|) * |s|` equivalence classes stored for the suffixes of lengths `2^k` with `k=0...log(|s|)`. Wouldn't that make the overall complexity O(n log n), n being string length? Is there another way to make the comparisons?

Comment: (Sorry, not suffixes, but rather the 2^k lengths taken across all cyclic shifts was the implementation I was reading about.)

Comment: @גלעדברקן is this inside the suffix array/LCP construction algorithm? Ukkonen is linear-time for O(1)-character alphabets, and to do the comparisons inside this algorithm, we're just using the LCP array to figure out where the first difference is (I guess we might need O(1)-time range min queries on top of it, but that's still technically linear-time.)

Comment: Ah - using the LCP array is another method to compare I wasn't aware or thought of. More to study. Thanks!

Comment: I wrote something rather verbose (added an answer) that seems to pass testing against brute force with string length 12 and k < n - 4 (longer strings take longer for my brute force :). It's using the charming CP suffix array O(n log n). (Didn't have time for Ukkonen or O(1) RMQ yet.) The main logic for this problem seems kind of tedious, though, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: (I did have a similar idea to yours to start but you helped me think about the middles.)

Answer (score 3):

Interesting task!

#### Update: step 5 incorrect. Here is correct one:

All combinations with length M, which consist of 3'th and 4'th remove operations are equal to this class of operations:
Zero or more 3 after that zero or more 4, like this regexp: (3)*(4)*
You can prove it:

1. 43 pair is equal to 33
2. 343 pair equal to 443.
3. Moreover 34...43 is equal to 44...43.

So you can pick rightmost 3 and with rule 3 make it the only one 3. And with rule 4 make transform all left 4 to 3.

any ->rule3-> 4...434...4 -> rule1-> 3...34...4

It leads to O(K^3) complexity of step 6 brute force.

---

#### Original answer

There are some ideas and solution that works nice in common

1. [More short word is smaller in lexicographical order] Wrong, as @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. mentinoed. All possible results will be equal length (Length-K), because we should use all of them.
2. Lexicographical order means: for semi-length words we match symbols from left to right until it equal. Result of word comparison is result of first different char comparison result. So minimization of i'th symbol is more important than minimization (i+j)'th symbol for all positive j.
3. So most important is first symbol minimization. Only first removal operation can influence on it. By first removal operation we try to place at first place minimal possible value (It will be minimal value from first K symbols). If there is some positions with minimal letter - we will pick leftmost one (we don't want to delete extra symbols and lost correct answer).
4. Now most important is second letter. So we want to minimize it too. We will make it like in 3'th step of algorithm. But, we use 2'nd remove operation and if we had some variants as minimal - we save all of them as **candidates**.
5. All combinations with length M, which consist of 3'th and 4'th remove operations are equal to only 2 combinations:

- all operations are 4'th: 44...44
- all operations are 4'th but the last one is 3: 44...43.
  So for every **candidate** we can check only two possibilities.

6. Brute force all **candidates** with both possibilities. Find minimal.

In common case this algorithm work's well. But in worst case it's weak. There is counterpoint: Maxlength string with same letter. Then we have K **candidates** and algorithm complexity will be O(K^2) - it's not good for this task.

For deal with it i think we can choose right candidate at 6'th step of algorithm:

6*. For two **candidates** - compare their suffix - letters after it. Candidate with smaller letter at same tail position (tail position counts from this candidate head position) is better for our purposes.

7*. Compare two possibilities form 5'th algorithm step and choose minimal.

Problem of this (*) approach - i cannot get a rigid proof that it's better solution. Most hard part, when one candidate is a prefix of another - we compare it letter by letter until smallest doesn't end. for example in string abcabcabc...abc with candidate at first and fourth position.

Comment: "More short word is smaller in lexicographical order" This is incorrect.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Thaknk you! Edit my answer

Comment: Moreover 5'th step doesn't correct. 34 doesn't equal to any of that two. Now i think that they are equal to zero or more 3 after that zero or more 4, like this: (3)*(4)*

Comment: `6*. For two candidates - compare their suffix - letters after it. Candidate with smaller letter at same tail position (tail position counts from this candidate head position) is better for our purposes.` What does this mean?  What is tail position?

Comment: @LearningMathematics For string abcabc we have two candidates: abcabc and abc. I mean that we compare this candidates letter by letter left to right. And Tail position is simply position in candidate string.

Answer (score 1):

A non-solution failing for abcbaa, *K* = 2
(Kudos to גלעד ברקן for [sharing a test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69024163/3789665).)

- find the minimum in the first *K*+1 elements at lowest 0-based index *l1*
- drop a prefix of length *l1* (remove 1st *l1* times) - done if *l1* = *K*
- find the minimum in the elements from 1 to 1 + *K - l1*, inclusive at *l2*
- "delete" elements from 1 to *l2* (if any)(remove 2nd *l2* times)
- starting with *l3* = 0 and while *K - l1 - l2 - l3* > 0,
   remove the larger of the last two elements and increase *l3*

Comment: What is your acid test for reputability?

Comment: You didn't address the case where there are multiple minimums in the first K + 1 element, which is the most difficult part of the question.

Comment: I did write *lowest* 0-based index.

Comment: You did. But why though?

Comment: I didn't think about the 3rd element of the result. I guess I'd be grateful for a shortish counterexample.

Comment: This maybe? `acabaa` K = 2, you need to correctly remove `b` and `c`

Comment: Um - b never gets to be one of the deletable characters.

Comment: Sorry about that, how about `acbaa`, K = 2?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236587/discussion-between-learning-mathematics-and-greybeard).

Comment: (Python implementation *seems* to work: not enough steam to give testing due diligence) A bounty text of `I need a working C++ solution for this Competitive Programming problem` without even disclosing where you encountered it looks an elaborate way not to get such.

Comment: (I'll have to re-read [Nikxp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68862016/3789665)) out for lack of steam.

Answer (score 1):

I will post this answer even though there is an accepted answer because I feel like all the other answers are more complex than they need to be. Below is a O(NK) algorithm that solves this, which can "easily" be made into an O(N) algorithm if a suffix tree is used to do the comparisons of the "middle" portions.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def lex_kr(x,K,k_r):
    """
    Get a lexicographically comparable subset of `x` for a given value of
    `k_r`.
    """
    N = len(x)
    assert k_r > 0 and k_r < K # check for corner cases
    k_l = K - k_r
    v_l = min(x[:k_l+1])
    v_r = min(x[-k_r-1:])

    lex = [v_l]
    lex += x[k_l+1:N-k_r-1]
    lex += [v_r]

    return lex

def lex_corner(x,K):
    """
    Get the two lexicographically comparable subsets of `x` for corner cases
    when `k_r=0` and `k_r=K`.
    """
    N = len(x)

    k_l = K
    v_l = min(x[:k_l+1])
    lex0 = [v_l]
    lex0 += x[k_l+1:]

    k_r = K
    v_r = min(x[-k_r-1:])
    lex1 = x[:N-k_r-1]
    lex1 += [v_r]

    return lex0,lex1


def min_lex(x,K):
    subsets = [ lex_kr(x,K,k_r) for k_r in range(1,K) ]
    subsets += lex_corner(x,K) # append the two corner cases
    return min(subsets)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    S = [ x for x in 'abacaaba' ]
    K = 2

    print(min_lex(S,K))
```

which prints `['a', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'a']`.

The comparisons of the `min` of the left and right (prefix & suffix) of the arrays can obviously be pre-computed in O(N) time in the function `lex_kr`.

The middle portion (i.e. `x[k_l+1:N-k_r-1]`) needs a clever trick to compare lexographically against all other middle portions efficiently. This can be done in O(1) per comparison using a suffix-tree/array as described in other answers (https://cp-algorithms.com/string/suffix-array.html) or a suffix automaton (https://cp-algorithms.com/string/suffix-automaton.html) with the latter being more complex but more efficient. Once implemented, this would yield an O(N) algorithm with less special cases to be checked than other answers.

Comment: @גלעדברקן: There were minor off-by-1 errors, they are fixed now.

Comment: @גלעדברקן: here is confirmation the off-by-1 fix addressed the problem: https://ideone.com/NNXid3

Comment: My understanding is that expressions like `min(x[:k_l+1])` would create a copy of the substring, (0, k_l+1), then iterate on each of those characters to find the smallest. Even if it were just an iteration, that's O(n * k) for all the runs called in `lex_kr(x,K,k_r) for k_r in range(1,K)`, if I understand correctly. Could you please adapt the code to represent your claim that *only* the middle comparisons would need to be addressed with the suffix tree in O(1), and that we would have at most O(n) such comparisons?

Comment: @גלעדברקן The code as written above is written as simple as possible with no optimizations. To address your comment specifically about the `min(x[:k_l+1])` creating copies, the idea is the code would have to be optimized to circumvent what you wrote. For example, the prefix and suffix can each be precomputed in O(N) time and space, requiring O(N) comparisons. There are many optimizations to be done to the above code, but it can be brought to an O(N) runtime, even without the use of a suffix tree, just carefully rewriting the comparisons in a specifically chosen order that would allow reuse.

Comment: Wow, O(n) without the suffix data structure. That would be awesome to see.